# Angular: Cannot load a component from a shared library

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a multiapp in angular.

In my projects folder I have muliply applications and also a  library.

Now I want to use a component from the library in application.

library module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UxLibraryComponent } from './ux-library.component';
import { RoundedComponent } from './buttons/rounded/rounded.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    UxLibraryComponent,
    RoundedComponent
  ],
  imports: [
  ],
  exports: [
    UxLibraryComponent,
    RoundedComponent
  ]
})
export class UxLibraryModule { }
```

library public api:

```
export * from './lib/ux-library.service';
export * from './lib/ux-library.component';
export * from './lib/ux-library.module';

export * from './lib/buttons/rounded/rounded.component';
```

library component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'uxlib-rounded',
  templateUrl: './rounded.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rounded.component.css']
})
export class RoundedComponent {

}
```

application feature module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';
import { UxLibraryModule } from 'projects/ux-library/src/public-api';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    UxLibraryModule
  ]
})
export class DashboardModule { }
```

html (application dashoard feature):

```
<p>application 1 dashboard works!</p>

<uxlib-rounded></uxlib-rounded>
```

There are no errors in my editor but my terminal returns:
Error: src/app/dashboard/dashboard.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'uxlib-rounded' is not a known element:

1. If 'uxlib-rounded' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'uxlib-rounded' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

Can someone help me with this issue.

Comment: This seems incorrect: `import { UxLibraryModule } from 'projects/ux-library/src/public-api';` You should import it from the dist folder instead. Have you build the library first? I expect something like `import { UxLibraryModule } from 'dist/ux-library';`

Comment: Also, most of the time, angular adds an entry to the tsconfig.json file with an alias path so after you have build the library you can just `import { UxLibraryModule } from 'ux-library';`

Comment: I had some delay issues with my vs code. Also te main issue was that I was not importing the dashboard module (feature module) into my app module.
I tested that multiple times but vs code had a delay issue. Because of the delay I was looking at other options. It's fixed now thanks.